# How to acces Application or ViewHandler within a filter

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

Using authentication in a filter and manually redirecting to a login site I need to gain access to the `Application` or `ViewHandler` to create a bookmarkable url using `ViewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(...)`.

This is necessary since my view-id's are being rewritten to clean-urls using 3rd-party framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible using the standard servlet API, so you really need to either manually create the `FacesContext`, or if it's a 3rd party URL-rewriting framework, check its documentation if they don't already provide any API for the purpose.

You could manually create the `FacesContext` based on `request` and `response` as follows:

```
public static FacesContext getFacesContext(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (facesContext == null) {
        LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY); 
        Lifecycle lifecycle = lifecycleFactory.getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE);
        FacesContextFactory facesContextFactory = (FacesContextFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        facesContext = facesContextFactory.getFacesContext(request.getServletContext(), request, response, lifecycle);
        facesContext.setViewRoot(facesContext.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(facesContext, ""));
        FacesContextWrapper.setCurrentInstance(facesContext);
    }

    return facesContext;
}

private static abstract class FacesContextWrapper extends FacesContext {
    protected static void setCurrentInstance(FacesContext facesContext) {
        FacesContext.setCurrentInstance(facesContext);
    }
}
```

Please note that this isn't considered "best practice". If there's a way without manually creating the `FacesContext`, by all means use it.

Comment: Oh man this is really not a nice workaround and i was happy that `getBookmarkabelURL` worked so easily with a 3rd-party framework. What about using an application-scoped bean to store the application or viewhandler and access that bean in the filter?

Comment: Doable, but looks still fishy. As an alternative, you could perhaps consider a `PhaseListener` instead of a filter. But you should keep in mind that this is tight-coupled to JSF and doesn't run on non-JSF requests and thus it may miss hits.

Comment: I prefer a PhaseListener over a filter for exactly that reason: you will have JSF context. If you, at some point in time, complete replace JSF, than you'll have to change these things too. It's easy as that.